# React Native ListView rows visible rows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have a list view in RN which has a list of component peopleView which has `employeeID` as its props.

```
    return <BillboardCard   id={employee.id} …employee onPress= { () => {
      // do something
     } }/>
```

Sample JSON for employee data

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "joe"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "john"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "mike"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "alex"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "sean"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to log metrics when a particular employee’s data is seen.

How can I do that?

It has to do with

```
onChangeVisibleRows() {

         // What do I write here? 
         console.log('onChangeVisibleRows called with', arguments);
    }
```

but I can't seem to find the ID there and only variables `s1,s2,s3 …. S12`?

I also wanted to know what is the variable `KEY` where is it used? and How is it different from ID?I have seen in props/ components sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

so onChangeVisibleRows is the correct method. This method receives to arguments:

**1. visibleRows**

It contains an object, where you will find all sectionIDs as a key and in the value an object where the key is the rowID and the value a bool if the row is visible.

**2. changedRows**

It contains the same data structure, but only for changed rows. This is the one you would use.

The rowID is the position in your dataSource. So you can call something like this to get the employee id.

```
console.log(employee[rowId])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id by `this.props.id`.

```
return <BillboardCard   id={employee.id} …employee onPress= { () => {
      // const empId = this.props.id;
     } }/>
```